# How I lock rotation on a UIViewController presented as modal form sheet?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit, ios9

I'm presenting a `UIViewController` modally with presentation style as Form Sheet, and it's not locking orientation when it appears as a form sheet.  The form sheet modal presentation style looks different when shown on the iPhone 6+ in landscape, or on the iPad in any rotation.

I'm presenting the VC via a storyboard segue

This same code works correctly in locking orientation on iPhone (except 6+), but does not work when style is form sheet.  How can I lock a modal form sheet in portrait on iPad or iPhone 6+?

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me, hope it works for u too

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let val = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    UIDevice .currentDevice() .setValue(val, forKey: "orientation");


}

override func shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait)
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  `UIDevice` only provides a `get` method for `orientation` so using this technique isn't documented or officially supported, and I'm not looking to introduce code like that.

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Did you read my comment?  I don't consider this a valid answer.

Comment: @AndyObusek - Did you ever find a better documented solution to this problem?